# Error "GetAuthenticationStateAsync was called before SetAuthenticationState" using AddSingleton on service dependent on AuthenticationStateProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a service with a dependency on AuthenticationStateProvider.  If I add my service using AddScoped, it works fine,  if I add with AddSingleton, I will get an exception when my service calls the GetAuthenticationStateAsync method of AuthenticationStateProvider.

> GetAuthenticationStateAsync was called before SetAuthenticationState.

I understand the different in scope, but I don't understand why that has the impact id does on AuthenticationStateProvider.

My Service:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    AuthenticationStateProvider _provider
    public MyService(AuthenticationStateProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider
    }

    public async Task<MyObject> DoThingsAsyc()
    {
        \\Exception happens here
        var user = (await _provider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;
        ...
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
```

Answer (score 0):

When we have a scoped instance, each time we load the page, a new instance of our AuthenticationStateProvider is created and inserted in the MyService. Whereas when we do a singleton, it keeps the exact same instance (Including the same AuthenticationStateProvider services). When we make MyService a singleton, that means that the AuthenticationStateProvider service is unable to be created per page load.

We can't use a service with a smaller lifetime. Scoped services only exist per-request, while singleton services are created once and the instance is shared.
Now only one instance of MyService exists in the app. But it wants to depend on AuthenticationStateProvider, which is Scoped, and is created per-request. AuthenticationStateProvider service isn't been created, thus no SetAuthenticationState.In  MyService you use`_provider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()` to call GetAuthenticationStateAsync before SetAuthenticationState. So the error will accour.